# Is there a way to use a google cloud storage bucket file as a local file?

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I tried using the format gs://bucket-name/file-name but it does not work (error given: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'gs://data-excel/Book1.xlsx'").

I want to use the [read-excel-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file) library to convert the excel file to MySQL and insert the data. It worked when I used /tmp/ as storage, but when it comes to larger files it does not work because it uses more memory than I have available. PD: I'm using the app engine standard environment.

I have been trying to read the cloud storage documentation but I cannot find a solution anywhere. I would be really grateful to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a VM or on your workstation, you can use [GCSFUSE](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse) (on linux/mac only) to mount a GCS bucket in a directory and interact with GCS as a local directory (be careful, you need to keep in mind that the system calls are wrapped in API calls and therefore the performance, and the cost aren't the same as a local storage).

If you use serverless product, App Engine, Cloud Functions or Cloud Run (for now), these product are stateless and you can't mount partition on it. The only way to achieve that is to download the file in the [/tmp directory](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/using-temp-files) (in memory file system), and then to perform the processing with the locally downloaded file.

Be careful, because it's in memory file system, if you don't clean manually the `/tmp` directory, you can run with out of memory issue. In addition, when the instance restart or scale up, you will lost the downloaded files; because it's only in memory and not persistent.

Comment: Hi Guillaume! Thanks for answering. I already tried uploading an excel file to /tmp/ and converting it to mysql, and it worked with small files. When I tried with larger files the app engine ran out of memory and it didn’t complete the process. That’s why I decided to use GCS but the thing is I don’t know what is the relative path to the files in GCS so I can use them in a script.

Comment: I’ll try with GCSFUSE and see how it goes.

Comment: What's the max size of your XLS file?

Comment: The file that I was trying to convert to MySQL was 6.89MB. And it ran out of memory, and I even tried to set the app engine to its maximum (F4_1G). The error that it gave me in the logs was: "Exceeded hard memory limit of 2048 MB with 2063 MB after servicing 1 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml." And the exceeded memory limit kept increasing when I Increased the instance class (at first it said 'exceeded hard memory limit of 256 mb with 307 mb...') . Some people in Stackoverflow had the same issue and switched to Kubernetes but I did not want to give up yet.

Comment: I can't use GCSFUSE if I am using App Engine, right?

Comment: Right, you can't. Only on VM or on your local (linux/mac) environment

Comment: It shouldn't take so much space in memory. You can consider up to 4 times the XLS file size. Are you sure that you haven't memory leak?

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll have to use GKE then. Thank you so much for answering my questions.

Comment: I'll check if I don't have a memory leak again.

Comment: On GKE, you can use autopilot if you want, it's managed for you, and you only pay for the memory/cpu time that your pods use. Perfect for batch processing for example!